# json array how to sort descending and top 1

Tags: postgresql

I have a jsonb field value like this:

```
fname, amount
-----  ------
Merry, [ { "pid": 5, "sales": 100 }, { "pid": 1, "sales": 20 }, { "pid": 3, "sales": 125 }, { "pid": 2, "sales": 55 } ]
Tom,   [ { "pid": 5, "sales": 20 },  { "pid": 1, "sales": 15 }, { "pid": 3, "sales": 110 }, { "pid": 2, "sales": 75 } ]
Susan, [ { "pid": 5, "sales": 132 }, { "pid": 1, "sales": 120 }, { "pid": 3, "sales": 122 }, { "pid": 2, "sales": 155 } ]
```

I want to show who has the highest sales amount, like below

```
fname, amount, pid
-----  ------  ---
Susan, 155,    2
Merry, 125,    3
Tom,   110,    3
```

I have tried below, but it doesn't show top 1

```
Select a.*, item_object, position from table1 a,
jsonb_array_elements(a.amount) with ordinality arr(item_object, position) Order by position desc
```

how to archive this with postgresql ?
thank you so much in advance

Don

Comment: Don't store tabular data in a JSON. Use a second table that has one row per `pid`. Then the problem will be very simple.

Answer (score 1):

"Sales" is a peculiar name for a column obviously containing people's first names, not sales.

You can use DISTINCT ON to get the top row per group.

```
Select distinct on (sales) sales, item_object from table1 a,
jsonb_array_elements(a.amount) arr(item_object) 
Order by sales, (item_object->>'sales')::int desc;
```

DISTINCT ON requires that you sort first by the 'group' column(s).  To get the final output sorted by something else, you would need to wrap it in another query with a different ORDER BY, giving something like this (also taking the opportunity to parse out and relabel some columns):

```
select * from (
   Select distinct on (sales) sales as fname, (item_object->'sales')::int true_sales, item_object->'pid' pid  
   from table1 a,
   jsonb_array_elements(a.amount) arr(item_object) 
   Order by sales, (item_object->>'sales')::int desc
) foo order by true_sales desc;
```

Comment: yes, you are correct it should be fname (I have corrected it), but your query doesn't work, it returns empty:

select * from (
   Select distinct on (fname) fname, (item_object->'sales')::int true_sales 
   from newtable a,
   jsonb_array_elements(a.amount) arr(item_object) 
   Order by fname, (item_object->>'sales')::int desc
) foo order by true_sales desc;

Comment: Works for me, I tested it before posting.  Maybe use https://dbfiddle.uk/ so we can see what is actually happening.